# Condition on DeploymentItem attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment

There are some cases where I need to deploy and some cases where I should not.
For example, when a build is queued for remote agent i.e. using `visual studio online` execute the `DeploymentItem` attribute. But when a debug from visual studio i.e. build locally I do not wish to execute the `DeploymentItem`.

Can I set condition like `if .. else` on the `DeploymentItem` attribute? If yes, please let me know how to. Do mention if any work around.

Some code just for reference:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"Mocks", "Mocks")]
public class CodedUITest
{ 
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use two different test settings files with different values for [`Enable deployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx#Anchor_5) option:

- when queuing for remote agent you should use settings with this option *enabled*;
- when building locally you should use settings with this option *disabled*.

---

[How to select test settings file in VS ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965929/2974754)

[Specifying test settings as argument to MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#testsettings)

Comment: Someone has downvoted the question as well as the answer. Also is trying to close the question. Any idea over this?

Comment: No idea whatsoever, there is no comment to explain the behavior/decision. If this repeats, without any explanation of reason, you can ask about it on meta. Don't dwell on it too much.